# Looking for Method to view Omniscript JSON in LWC override element

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, vlocity

We are using an LWC overwrite on a Text element in an Omniscript.

We have a requirement to view the current JSON data in the Omniscript at runtime in order to populate values inside of the LWC being used for the override element.

Is there a way to view the Omniscripts' JSON data inside the LWC javascript code? (Or alternatively send data to the LWC override element?)

(note: we are able to use the omniApplyCallResp() method to write data back to the Omniscript JSON. We just need to be able to read the JSON as well)

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have got answer. You can use

```
console.log("omniJsonData", JSON.stringify(this.omniJsonData));
```

Answer (score 0):

add json-data={jsonData}  in html and in the js call this.jsonData variable to see the data

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
_jsonData;

set jsonData(val){ 
    if(val) {this._jsonData= val;}
};

get jsonData(){
    return this._jsonData;
}
```

You need to include set / get in your lwc override.
you can check the Omniscript json data in your function
as :

```javascript
checkingOmniscriptData(){
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.jsonData));
}
```